modular arithmetic: number representations in base $b$ (mod $b^2-1$)
I am studying number representations in base $b$, and in order to understand the method of "casting out 9s", "casting out 11s", and "casting out 99s" for a generic base, the following observations have been made:
$$ 
\sum_{k=0}^p a_k \cdot b^k \equiv \sum_{k=0}^p a_k \mbox{ (mod }b-1),
$$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^p a_k \cdot b^k \equiv \sum_{k=0}^p (-1)^k \cdot a_k \mbox{ (mod }b+1),
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=0}^p a_k \cdot b^k \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{p/2} a_{2k+1}a_{2k} \mbox{ (mod }b^2-1),
$$
(later edited) where the terms on the right-side $a_{2k+1}a_{2k}$ are just 2-digits numbers, not products, which I pointed out as "$\cdot$".
I can easily derive the first two formulas, but I am stuck with the third one. Of course, I know that $b^2-1=(b+1)(b-1)$, but I may be missing some properties properties of modular arithmetic. Can you help me?
EDIT
After checking the 'casting out 99s' method, I realized that $a_{2k+1}a_{2k}$​ is not the product of the two coefficients, but the number obtained by juxtaposing them. So we just sum pairs of digits. But anyway, why is that the case?

Are we assuming $p$ is even here?

I edited the post, and now this makes sense even if $p$ is odd; the question was aswered while I was replying your comment lol

Casting $,b^2-1,$ is simply the analog of casting nines in base $b^2,,$ i.e. put $,b\to b^2,$ in your  first formula, see here. $\ \ $

See here for an example of casting $99$'s. $\ \ $

See that $b^k \equiv b^{2\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}b^{k-2\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} \equiv b^{k'} \pmod{b^2-1}$, where $k' \in {0,1}$ and $k\equiv k' \pmod{2}$. Thus, when you look at the sum $a_{2j}b^{2j} + a_{2j+1}b^{2j+1}$, you get:
$a_{2j}b^{2j} + a_{2j+1}b^{2j+1} \equiv a_{2j+1}b^1+a_{2j} = a_{2j+1}a_{2j}$, the desired two-digit number in base $b$

It was so easy... sometimes one can't see obvious things. Thank you !
